# MySql serverless WebRTC works quite well, but ICE Failure rate too high: how can I improve it?

Tags: mysql, webrtc, serverless, stun, ice

I am a retired software engineer OK with PHP and jQuery but not with node.js (which I would rather avoid). I have been tasked by our non-profit organization for the elderly, to add to our website a very simple app (a video chat page) so that at the touch of a button two far apart elderly people can communicate from any web-enabled device (i.e. most phones, iOS, android, tablets, PCs, and most main browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge).

Thus I have implemented a simple WebRTC video-chat module. This page receives three parameters via querystring (two usernames and a role, as for example “Alice, Bob, Initiator" (or "Alice, Bob, Responder") such that a peer-to-peer webRTC communication is established at the touch of a button (see example page via links supplied—the hosting site is unrelated).

My current implementation works quite well and communication is established via a STUN server service: we currently cycle at random through Google’s free “test” STUN servers--and signalling is done by passing/conveying SDP offer/answer messages between Initiator and Responder via a short (about 30 second) Ajax/MySQL database polling in one-second cycles. It works quite well, but we get too many iceConnectionState “fails" (often repeated in sequence) frustrating and confusing our users.

Our iceConnectionState is "completed" and runs perfectly about 50% of the time but fails the other 50%: is there anything you can point out that could/should be substantially improved?

Our goal is that (ideally) 90-99% of communications are established “phone-call like” within 20-30 seconds or less, with no--or very few--"ICE Failures”.

What are we doing wrong?

I read all I could find on SO but found no applicable information. Thank you in advance for any help.

To run the code copy (or click) https://Wisewords.fun/WebCall.php?Role=Initiator&Giver=Bob&Taker=Alice (in one device) and https://Wisewords.fun/WebCall.php?Role=Responder&Giver=Bob&Taker=Alice (in the other--notice only "Role" differs, and that only the Initiator/Giver can start communication).

Code is attached:

```
<?php session_start();
    /* 
    //      ################################################################################################
    //      FILE:           WebCall.php (WebRTC TEST)
    //      requires Role, Giver and Taker as querystring params:
    //      Role can be either Initiator or Responder and Giver and Taker are "Nicks" or usernames
    //      (for this example the Initiator is the Giver and the only one who can start the call)
        
    // Below is the DB structure where SDP messages are temporarily stored and exchanged
    
    DB Table: WRTC_Charla
    
    1   WRTC_IdPrimary      int(11)         
    2   WRTC_Giver          varchar(100)    
    3   WRTC_Taker          varchar(100)    
    4   WRTC_Offer          text    
    5   WRTC_Answer         text    
    6   WRTC_Status         varchar(50) 
    7   WRTC_TimeOffered    timestamp
        
    //      ################################################################################################    
    */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        body,html{
            font-size: 1em;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <center>
    "<b>https://Wisewords.fun/WebCall.php</b>"<br>Connects two devices over WebRTC through DB SDP polling<br><br>To run use: <font color=green>https://Wisewords.fun/WebCall.php?Role=Initiator&Giver=Bob&Taker=Alice</font> (in one device)<br>and<br><font color=green>https://Wisewords.fun/WebCall.php?Role=Responder&Giver=Bob&Taker=Alice</font> (in the other).<br>(notice only "Role" differs, and <b>only <i>Initiator</i></b> can start communication)<hr>

    <? if (strtoupper($_GET['Role'])=='INITIATOR') { ?>
        You are Giver '<? echo $_GET['Giver']; ?>' and your Role is '<? echo strtoupper($_GET['Role']); ?>' and the Taker is: '<? echo $_GET['Taker']; ?>'
    <? } else {?>
        You are Taker '<? echo $_GET['Taker']; ?>' and your Role is '<? echo strtoupper($_GET['Role']); ?>' and the Giver is: '<? echo $_GET['Giver']; ?>'
    <? } ?>

    <br>
    Connection Status:<span style=color:green id=ConnectionStatus>??</span>
    <br><br>
    <video id="v1" height="120" width="160" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
    <video id="v2" height="120" width="160" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <br>
    <? if (strtoupper($_GET['Role'])=='INITIATOR') { ?>
        <button id="button" onclick="createOffer(); this.disabled=true; this.style.backgroundColor='gainsboro';" style="background:lime; font-size: 1.2em; padding:2%; border-radius: 15px;">START (Initiator Only)</button>
        <br>
    <? }; ?>
    <br>
    <textarea disabled id="offer" placeholder="Paste offer here" 
    onselect="
        offer.style.backgroundColor='gold';
    "
    onchange="
        offer.style.backgroundColor='gold';
    "
    oninput="
        offer.style.backgroundColor='gold';
    "
    ></textarea>
    <textarea disabled id="answer" placeholder="Answer shows here" onselect="
        $('#answer').css({'background':'lime'});
    "></textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea id="MsgBoard" style="width:70%; height:100px; overflow-y: auto; font-size: 1em; padding:2%;"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input id="chat" placeholder="Type here" disabled style="width:70%; font-size: 1em; padding:2%;" onselect="
        $('#chat').css({'background':'aqua'});
    "></input><br>
    </center>
  </body>
  
    <script>
        // GLOBALS START #############################################################################
        var globalMyRole='';
        var globalGiverNick='';
        var globalTakerNick='';     
        // GLOBALS ENDED #############################################################################
                
        globalMyRole = '<? echo $_GET['Role']; ?>';
        globalMyRole = globalMyRole.toUpperCase();
        if (globalMyRole=='INITIATOR') globalMyRole='Giver';
        if (globalMyRole=='RESPONDER') globalMyRole='Taker';        
        globalGiverNick='<? echo $_GET['Giver']; ?>';
        globalTakerNick='<? echo $_GET['Taker']; ?>';

        DeleteConnectionRecord(); // Initial DB cleanup of potentially undeleted previous records
        

// webrtc core starts ###########################################
/*
The original sources of this code are:
https://github.com/svarunan/serverless-webrtc
and
https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/nnc13tw2/

pc = PeerConnection
dc = DataChannel        
*/

        var ESTE=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);       
        var server = { urls: "stun:stun"+ESTE+".l.google.com:19302" };
        //var server = { urls: "stun:51.145.230.94" };
        
        var dc, pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [server] });
        pc.ontrack = e => v2.srcObject = e.streams[0];
        pc.ondatachannel = e => dcInit(dc = e.channel);
        pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => {log(pc.iceConnectionState); /* alert(pc.iceConnectionState); */}
        
        var haveGum = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true})
          .then(stream => pc.addStream(v1.srcObject = stream))
          .catch(function(err) { alert(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
                
        function dcInit() {
            dc.onopen = () => {
                globalUAM_WRTC_Status="Conectados!"; 
                DeleteConnectionRecord();
                log("Chat!");
                chat.select();
                chat.disabled = false;
                chat.style.backgroundColor='aqua';
            }
            dc.onmessage = e => log(e.data);
        }
        
        function createOffer() {
          button.disabled = true;
          dcInit(dc = pc.createDataChannel("chat"));
          haveGum.then(() => pc.createOffer()).then(d => pc.setLocalDescription(d))
            .catch(log);
          pc.onicecandidate = e => {
            if (e.candidate) return; // no sdp was received
            offer.value = pc.localDescription.sdp; // sdp was received
            offer.select(); // selects the whole sdp 
            answer.placeholder = "Paste answer here";
            AjaxGiverStoresOfferInDBToStart(); // Here is where we start saving and interacting SDPs to exchange them remotely via DB
          };
        };
        
        offer.onkeypress = e => {
          if (!enterPressed(e) || pc.signalingState != "stable") return;
          button.disabled = offer.disabled = true;
          var desc = new RTCSessionDescription({ type:"offer", sdp:offer.value });
          pc.setRemoteDescription(desc)
            .then(() => pc.createAnswer()).then(d => pc.setLocalDescription(d))
            .catch(log);
          pc.onicecandidate = e => {
            if (e.candidate) return;
            answer.focus();
            answer.value = pc.localDescription.sdp;
            answer.select();
          };
        };
        
        answer.onkeypress = e => {
          if (!enterPressed(e) || pc.signalingState != "have-local-offer") return;
          answer.disabled = true;
          var desc = new RTCSessionDescription({ type:"answer", sdp:answer.value });
          pc.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch(log);
        };
        
        chat.onkeypress = e => {
          if (!enterPressed(e)) return;
          dc.send(chat.value);
          log(chat.value);
          chat.value = "";
          document.getElementById('MsgBoard').scrollTop = document.getElementById('MsgBoard').scrollHeight;
        };
        
        var enterPressed = e => e.keyCode == 13;
        var log = msg => MsgBoard.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
        
        if (window.isSecureContext) {
          //alert('issecure for privacy');
        }
// webrtc core ended ###########################################

        
        
  
        var i=0;
        var globalUAM_WRTC_Status='';
        if(window.globalPoller){ clearInterval(window.globalPoller); };
        globalPoller=setInterval(ConectionManager, 1000); 

        function ConectionManager(){            
            AjaxReadUAM_WRTC_Status();
            $('#ConnectionStatus').html(globalUAM_WRTC_Status +' '+ i++);
            
            if ((globalUAM_WRTC_Status=='GiverOfferStoredToDB') && (globalMyRole=='Taker')) {
                TakerPastesGiverOfferAsOwnOffer(); // if succesful globalUAM_WRTC_Status = TakerPastedGiverOfferAsOwnOffer
            }
            
            if ((globalUAM_WRTC_Status=='TakerAnswerStoredInDB') && (globalMyRole=='Giver')) {
                GiverReadsTakersAnswerFromDb();
            }           
        }
        
        function DeleteConnectionRecord(){          
            var params = 'GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick;
            if ((!globalGiverNick) || (!globalTakerNick)) {alert('problem: Users not well defined')}
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_CharlaCleanup.php',   // Cleans connection status
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                        $('#ConnectionStatus').html('Connected via WebRTC!');                       
                        if(window.globalPoller){ clearInterval(window.globalPoller); };               
                  }, async: false,
                  error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 1');
                  }
            });     
        }
        
        function AjaxReadUAM_WRTC_Status(){
            var params = 'GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick;
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_ReadCharlaStatus.php', // Reads connection status
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        globalUAM_WRTC_Status=data;  // Updates local global in Taker
                        $('#ConnectionStatus').html(data);
                    } else { 
                        globalUAM_WRTC_Status='';
                        $('#ConnectionStatus').html('');
                    }
                }, async: false,
                  error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 2');
                  }
            });             
        }

        function AjaxSetUAM_WRTC_Status(NewStatus){
            var params =    'GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick+'&NewStatus='+NewStatus;
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_SetCharlaStatus.php', // Set connection status
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        globalUAM_WRTC_Status=data; // updates local global in Taker
                        $('#ConnectionStatus').html(data);
                    } else { 
                        globalUAM_WRTC_Status='';
                        $('#ConnectionStatus').html('');
                    }
                }, async: false,
                  error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 3');
                  }
            });             
        }

        function AjaxGiverStoresOfferInDBToStart(){
            if (!globalGiverNick) {alert('no Giver nick'); return false;}
            if (!globalTakerNick) {alert('no Taker nick'); return false;}
            if (offer.value.length<20) {alert('no offer.value'); return false;}

            var params =    'OfferValue='+offer.value+
                            '&GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick+
                            '&UAM_WRTC_Status=GiverOfferStoredToDB';
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_StoreOffer.php',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        if (data=='GiverOfferStoredToDB') { // success in storing
                            globalUAM_WRTC_Status=data; // updates process status
                            $('#ConnectionStatus').html(globalUAM_WRTC_Status);
                        } else {
                            alert('Problem 4');
                        };
                    } else { 
                        alert('Problem 5');
                    }
                }, async: false,
                  error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 6');
                  }
            }); 
        }

        function TakerPastesGiverOfferAsOwnOffer(){
            var params = 'GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick;
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_RetrieveGiverOfferFromDB.php',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        if (data!='NADA') { // data was found
                            offer.value = data; // Stores Giver offer into Taker's textbox
                            $('#offer').css({'background':'gold'});
                            //button.disabled = offer.disabled = true;  // IMPORTANT: KEEP REMMED ( and do not disable button )!!!
                            var desc = new RTCSessionDescription({ type:"offer", sdp:offer.value });
                            pc.setRemoteDescription(desc)
                              .then(() => pc.createAnswer()).then(d => pc.setLocalDescription(d))
                              .catch(log);
                            pc.onicecandidate = e => {
                              if (e.candidate) return;
                              answer.focus();         
                              answer.value = pc.localDescription.sdp;
                              answer.select();
                              $('#answer').css({'background':'lime'});                        
                              AjaxTakerStoresAnswerInDB();                                                
                            };
                        } else {
                            alert('ooops in TakerPastesGiverOfferAsOwnOffer');
                        };
                    } else { 
                        //alert('Problem 7');
                    }
                  }, async: false,
                  error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 8');
                  }
            }); 
        }


        function AjaxTakerStoresAnswerInDB(){
            if (answer.value.length<20) {return false;}
            var params = 'GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick+'&AnswerValue='+answer.value;
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_StoreAnswererAnswerInDB.php',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        if (data=='AnswerStored') {
                                globalUAM_WRTC_Status='TakerAnswerStoredInDB';
                        };
                    } else {
                        //unrem for development  logToChatDiv('Answer NOT stored (yet?) to DB by Answerer'); 
                    }
                }, async: false,
                  error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 9');
                  }
            }); 
        }

        function GiverReadsTakersAnswerFromDb(){
            var params = 'GiverNick='+globalGiverNick+'&TakerNick='+globalTakerNick;
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',                                      
                  url: 'TWRTC_InitiatorChecksIfAnswerInDB.php',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: params,       
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        if (data!='NADA') { // data found
                            answer.value=data;
                            answer.select();
                            var desc = new RTCSessionDescription({ type:"answer", sdp:answer.value });
                            pc.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch(log);
                            globalUAM_WRTC_Status='CharlaCompleted';
                        };
                    } else { 
                        //alert('??');
                    }
                }, async: false,
                error: function(error,x,y) {
                      alert('Problem 10');
                }
            });
        }

        
    </script>  
</html>
```

Comment: you want to make a new teamviewer, but you problem lies that you used the free stunnel and don't use your own server, so you will allways have falures, because other people also want to use them.

Comment: Thank you @nbk, so I believe you suggest I use a dedicated STUN server instead, right? I believe my current hosting/ISP cannot offer me that (and I wouldn't know how to deploy one) but I will look into it. Any suggestions about the STUN server (or service) I should use/implement?

Comment: you should go th server fault, to see if your current cinfiguration is enough, because every encryted tunnel needs resources, not a lot but 50 or so use a lot of resources, you can run it in a vm. Depending which linux you have you should check if you can instal the package and also check the webseite for more information